# How to perform a rolling average for irregular time intervals in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe of the form `df` :

```
timeCol      dataCol
2              5
9.135          8    
11             4
12             6
```

I want to do a rolling mean over a 3 second interval over `dataCol` such that it returns a dataframe of the form, `new_df` :

```
startTime    endTime    meanCol
0               3        5.0
1               4        5.0
2               5        5.0
3               6        0.0
4               7        0.0
5               8        0.0
6               9        0.0   
7               10       8.0
8               11       6.0
9               12       6.0
10              13       5.0
11              14       5.0
12              15       6.0
```

Notice, in `new_df`, for example, for time ranges (8-11) and (9-12), the value of 6.0 is returned (because `mean(8,4)=6.0` and `mean(8,4,6)=6.0` respectively. All columns are float type. `time_col` will always be ordered. What is an efficient, pythonic way of achieving this?

Comment: Is your timeseries dataframe always going to be in order based on the `timeCol`?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `numpy` board-cast

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'startTime':np.arange(13),'endTime':np.arange(13)+3})
s=ori.timeCol[:,None]
s1=(df.startTime.values-s<=0)&(df.endTime.values-s>=0)
df['New']=ori.dataCol.dot(s1)/s1.sum(axis=0)
df
    startTime  endTime  New
0           0        3  5.0
1           1        4  5.0
2           2        5  5.0
3           3        6  NaN
4           4        7  NaN
5           5        8  NaN
6           6        9  NaN
7           7       10  8.0
8           8       11  6.0
9           9       12  6.0
10         10       13  5.0
11         11       14  5.0
12         12       15  6.0
```

Comment: Thanks @WeNYoBen. Could you tell me what ori is in this case?

Comment: @Melsauce aha , ori in my is your df

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Source data
data = {
    'timeCol': [2, 9.135, 11, 12],
    'dataCol': [5, 8, 4, 6]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# Build list of rows based on time series
rows = []
for startTime in range(12):
    endTime = startTime + 3
    print(startTime, ' to ', endTime)
    # Get only rows from source data that match current time interval
    filtered = df.loc[(df['timeCol'] >= startTime) &
                      (df['timeCol'] <= endTime)]

    # Append current row, including mean of matching source rows
    rows.append([startTime, endTime, filtered['dataCol'].mean()])

# Create final dataframe, replacing any missing values with 0
res = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=['startTime', 'endTime', 'meanCol']).fillna(0)
print(res)
```

You could also build the result set first, then loop through it and calculate the average for each row in that.